# Post FB status from website admin, without pop up login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I just wondering if this can be done, because it can from twitter and linkedin, so i need to build like a blog that when i post the blog it would be post on fb,twitter and linkedin...

so far run well with twitter api and linkedin, but i am facing hard with FB when you want to post then you should login on FB or pop up fb login.

i just wondering if there is API that we can login from the configuration that we had..like api key, client id,etc..i found on twitter it can so we don't have to login to twitter first to make it work? Please if any of you have experience or deal with this and how to solve it..thank you so much before!! i am very appreciate it..thanks!

best regards,
Harrison

Comment: i am not sure whether  we can do that. But, once you have FB installed in device, i guess we get the integrate with internal credential and we might to skip log-in. i too eagerly looking for any best answers.

Comment: oh hi thank you for quick response @HariRam hmm unfortunately this is web application might be not used on mobile device, because it's admin part and not really responsive yet...but if on desktop i wondering if they should always login to facebook first..hmm i just wondering...if it can like silent login from API...because this post is from the owner..

i mean i am understand if it just like button or share button so need login to where it will be shared..i mean FB owner who want to share..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice workaround would be to get a short-lived access token, convert it to a long-term access token and use it.

Short-lived access token generally lasts for an hour or two whereas the long-term access tokens have a life span of 60 days from the time of its creation. Please note that an access token is expired or dead when you update your password, de-authorize the app,deactivate your account.

See this in code:

**Step to generate short-lived access token**:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent
&client_id=<app_id>
&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>
&scope=<set_of_permission>
```

Make the required changes and go to this URL, login and grant the permissions, on the next page you will be redirected to your website with short-lived access_token appended to the `<redirect_uri>`

For example: `http://www.yourwebsite.com/#access_token=CAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`<short_access_token>` = `CAAxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Copy the entire string between `#access_token=` and `&expires_in=xxxx`

**Step to generate long-term access token**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token
&client_id=<app_id>
&client_secret=<app_secret_key>
&fb_exchange_token=<short_access_token>
```

Copy the string between `access_token=` and `&expires=xxxxxxx`

At this step you have a long-term access_token which will last for 60 days from the time of its creation. You can check it life span by converting the value of `expires` to days/hours.

Use this token to do almost anything via Graph API from the server side. Please note, I mentioned server-side as the Long-term access token is very sensitive and can be used to make changes,updates to your account.

P.S.: **Long-term access token doesn't require you to be logged-in, so it has its own advantages and disadvantages.**

Comment: Hi Nishant Ghodke thank you for the answer..ok so at least admin should login once then we generate long access token right? ok i think i understand let me try it first..thank you for your solution / suggestion..thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the person on whose timeline you would like to post should login.